# Negative lookahead ends match before the last character I need

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking to identify parts of a string that are hex.

So if you consider the string

CHICKENORBEEFPIE, the match would be BEEF.

To do this I came up with this expression `/[A-F0-9]{2,}(?![^A-F0-9])/g`

This works perfectly - except it only matches BEE, not BEEF. Unless BEEF happened to be at the end of the string.

Comment: you mean `(?![A-F0-9])` or `(?=[^A-F0-9])`, `(?![^A-F0-9])` is double negation

Comment: Whats the issue with `[A-F0-9]{2,}` ?

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul basically what I was trying to achieve was that the match ended after BEEF, so I basically match A-F0-9 and then stop when there's something that doesn't match A-F0-9.

Comment: @AdityaGupta the issue with that is it would not stop after BEEF, it would include PIE.

Comment: I checked [here](https://www.regextester.com/?fam=102820/). Both PCRE and javascript are working. Could you recheck.

Answer (score 1):

The negative lookahead `(?![^A-F0-9])` means: do not match anything followed by any characters other than A-F, 0-9. Which translates to match pattern followed by A-F, 0-9. Your regex is matching 'BEE' because it is followed by F, which satisfies the condition.

If you want to identify sequences of two or more characters that are hex code, just eliminate the negative lookahead altogether.
`/[A-F0-9]{2,}/g` translates to: Find as many matches, a pattern consisting of A-F or 0-9 that are 2 or more characters long.

Comment: `(?![^A-F0-9])` is not exactly the same as `(?=[A-F0-9])` because the first can match an empty string

Answer (score 0):

It is because the last part of your regex: `(?![^A-F0-9])`

Because of that, you are matching any strings that aren't followed by a non-hex character... which ultimately means to find strings where the next character **is** a hex character.

You could either remove the `^` or remove that whole piece altogether as it isn't necessary. The following will retrieve what you are looking for: `/[A-F0-9]{2,}/g`

Answer (score 0):

- `[A-F0-9]{2,}(?![A-F0-9])` will match what is expected, however negative lookahead is superfluous because quantifier are greedy by default.
- `[A-F0-9]{2,}(?![^A-F0-9])` doesn't work because assertion is that following character must *not* be any character *except* A-F0-9 (double negation).

the reason why the last character `F` in `BEEF` is not matched is that after matching `BEEF`, negtaive lookahead fails `P` is in `[^A-F0-9]` which makes backtrack to `BEE` which success because `F` is not in `[^A-F0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the given result with pair-based values you can use `/([A-F0-9]{2})+/g`, if not (if it doesn't matter whether it's odd or not) you can use `/[A-F0-9]{2,}/g` instead.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Use

> /[A-F0-9]{2,}(?![^A-F0-9])*/g